# Blend Mode doesn't work for ImageView

Tags: java, javafx

I have two image that is

[image]

and this:

[image]

I need to place that image (stacked) in a single `ImageView`. I tried to use blend mode, but doesn't work for ImageView like

```
    Group group = new Group(); 
    group.setBlendMode(BlendMode.SRC_OVER);


    // tempImage is array of buffered Images
    for(int i=0; i < tempImage.length ;i++){
      if(tempImage[i] != null){  

         ImageView view = new ImageView();
         Image im  = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempImage[i], 
                 null );
         view.setImage(im);
         group.getChildren().add(view); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: wont BlendMode with SRC_OVER put the second image on top of the first image?

Comment: What mode?? I  tried all other mode... but cannot doing that thing.....

Comment: may be because `BlendMode` doesn't offer what you are looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Just a little trick, instead of using `BlendMode`use a `HBox`, add the images inside the HBox and set the `HBox inside the Group`

```
Group group = new Group(); 
HBox box = new HBox


// tempImage is array of buffered Images
for(int i=0; i < tempImage.length ;i++){
  if(tempImage[i] != null){  

     ImageView view = new ImageView();
     Image im  = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(tempImage[i], 
             null );
     view.setImage(im);
     box.getChildren().add(view); 
  }
}
group.getChildren.add(box);
```

*But this wont help you to get the new image, guess you don't even need it !*

Comment: Thats not work. I think there is no difference between Group and Hbox.

Comment: I see this from internet: 
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1639628&seqNum=3
but that  using javaFX script

Comment: You must read the blog to understand that BlendMode id used to merge two images in pixels/color and not to put them beside each other

Comment: OK, now for my problem, Is there any way to change opacity some part of Image? Like Image above, I need to make all area of second Image full transparent expet the green line. So I can combine both of them to make a "stacked Image" of plot